# In my for-loop, how do I change the index to a string?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this section of code that is constantly repeated.

```
g_materialAmbientIndex[0] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[0].ambient");
g_materialDiffuseIndex[0] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[0].diffuse");
g_materialSpecularIndex[0] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[0].specular");

g_materialAmbientIndex[1] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[1].ambient");
g_materialDiffuseIndex[1] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[1].diffuse");
g_materialSpecularIndex[1] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[1].specular");

g_materialAmbientIndex[2] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[2].ambient");
g_materialDiffuseIndex[2] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[2].diffuse");
g_materialSpecularIndex[2] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[2].specular");
```

I want to put it into a for loop but I am having problems with the string argument. Here is my function below. I keep getting an error that says:

> no suitable conversion func from "std::basic_string....." to "const GLchar*" exists

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MATERIALS; i++)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    string str = ss.str();

    g_materialAmbientIndex[i] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[" + str + "].ambient");
    g_materialDiffuseIndex[i] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[" + str + "].diffuse");
    g_materialSpecularIndex[i] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, "uMaterialProperties[" + str + "].specular");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

> no suitable conversion func from "std::basic_string....." to "const GLchar*" exists

means, that the result type of `"uMaterialProperties[" + str + "].ambient"` is `std::string`, but [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml) expects `const GLchar *` as type for the input parameter and there is no automatic conversion from `std::string` to `const GLchar *`.

You can use [`std::string::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) to get a pointer to the content of the `std::string`, which has the type `const char *` and can be converted to `const GLchar *`:

```
glGetUniformLocation( g_shaderProgramID, 
    ("uMaterialProperties[" + str + "].ambient").data() );
```

Your code should look somehow like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_MATERIALS; i++)
{
    std::string str = "uMaterialProperties[" + std::to_string(i);

    g_materialAmbientIndex[i] = glGetUniformLocation( g_shaderProgramID,
        (str + "].ambient").data() );
    g_materialDiffuseIndex[i] = glGetUniformLocation( g_shaderProgramID,
        (str + "].diffuse").data() );
    g_materialSpecularIndex[i] = glGetUniformLocation( g_shaderProgramID,
        (str + "].specular").data() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you everything you need to know:

`no suitable conversion func from "std::basic_string....." to "const GLchar*" exists`

So the method doesn't know how to deal with an `std::string` - it expects a `GLchar*`. The first thing you should try is a regular `char*` via `str.c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an `int`eger to a string representation, use the [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function.

Then do something like this:

```
auto str = "uMaterialProperties[" + std::to_str(i) + "].ambient";
g_materialAmbientIndex[i] = glGetUniformLocation(g_shaderProgramID, str.c_str());
```